# MVVM: Trigger method on property changed with Fody.PropertyChanged

Tags: c#, mvvm, inotifypropertychanged, fody-propertychanged

I'd like to run a method on property changed. I'd like my code to compile to something like this:

```
public string Property
    {
        get { return _property; }
        set
        {
            _property= value;
            IWantToCallFromHere(); // I want to inject this call
            NotifyPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
```

Comment: This code have to be _generated_ by foddy from `public string Property { get; set; }`

Comment: I just read about Fody. Let me help to understand it. If we just write Public property with get set, then compiler automatically generate code for us ? If I want to perform any logic in my Set property then where will I write using Fody ? Can we edit code that auto generated  code by Fody ?

Answer (score 1):

This is described in the Wiki in the page named [On_PropertyName_Changed](https://github.com/Fody/PropertyChanged/wiki/On_PropertyName_Changed).

Essentially you add a method with the naming convention `private void OnYourPropertyNameChanged()`

A complete example of what you would like to achieve is as follows:

```cs
public string Property
{
    get; set;
}

private void OnPropertyChanged()
{
    IWantToCallFromHere();
}
```

which gets translated into

```cs
private string _property;
public string Property
{
    get => _property; 
    set
    {
        if(_property != value)
        {
            _property = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
            NotifyPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
}

private void OnPropertyChanged()
{
    IWantToCallFromHere();
}
```